# Problemas al decodificar mi JWT de cognito usando laravel

Tags: laravel-5, jwt, cognito

Al querer decodificar mi JWT que uso de cognito me muestra el siguiente error:

```
"kid" invalid, unable to lookup correct key
```

Esto sucede decodificarlo, la manera en que lo hago es la siguiente

```php
$jwksJson = file_get_contents('https://cognito-idp.xx-xxxx-x.amazonaws.com/xx-xxxx-x_xxxxxxxxx/.well-known/jwks.json');
$jwks = json_decode($jwksJson, true);
$decode = JWT::decode($token, $jwks, ['RS256']);
```

Segun entiendo esto se debe a que la llave publica no es la correcta pero en este caso, segu lo que vi si coinciden entonces no se si estoy hacieno algo mal al obtener las credenciales, que puedo hacer para solucionar esto.

Estoy usando `Laravel 5.7` y `Firebase/JWT`